# Two rows div layout. Building flexible layout that should adapt to different screen sizes

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to build a flexible layout that should adapt to different screen sizes as the following pictures show. 
It's basically two div rows, occupying each 50% of the vertical size of the screen. 
Top div is a container to hold pictures and bottom div will display a leaflet map. 
I'd like the Image div to keep aspect ratio so image is not deformed, ans Map div to adapt horizontally.

So far, my code is basic and looks like this :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="Top div">
        <div id='image'>Image</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Bottom div">
        <div id='map'>Map</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea of the CSS style I should add to each div to achieve this layout ?

[Image layout desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vse4v.png)

[Image layout smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Pep.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Flexbox to achieve this layout. Refer to my CSS below and check out the attached [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mikehermary/pen/JjoOBpq).

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#Top {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
#image {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 3rem;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
#Bottom {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}
#map {
    padding: 5rem;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason you cannot use flexbox you can achieve this easily. The main trick is to add an element to act as a wrapper to the image, set a height/width to this element and then set the `max-width`/`max-height` on the image to 100%. This way it will scale without deforming.

To achieve `occupying each 50% of the vertical size of the screen` you can set the height to 50vh.

```css
#map {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.section {
  height: 50vh;
}

.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.sample-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="Top div" class="section img-container">
       <img class="sample-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/180" alt="image" />
    </div>
    <div id="Bottom div" class="section">
        <div id='map'>Map</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion ! I'll try to adapt to my code that is a bit more complicated than what I described here. The first test of your code shows that a blank appears between the map and the image and the images sticks to top of screen when screen is narrower than the image. Is there a way to adapt map height (even if this height grows over 50%) to have the screen filed without blank space between the two elements ?